# Query Realm for all objects based on the size of a RLMArray property?

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, realm

We're trying to write a Realm query to retrieve all objects where the size of a RLMArray property is a certain number. The Realm model looks like this:

```
class Foo: RLMObject {
    dynamic var people = RLMArray(objectClassName: User.className())
}
```

And multiple iterations of the query we've tried without success are as follows:

```
// 'Invalid predicate expressions', reason: 'Predicate expressions must compare a keypath and another keypath or a constant value'
let results = Foo.objectsWhere("people[SIZE] = %d", 2)

// 'Invalid predicate', reason: 'RLMArray predicates must contain the ANY modifier'
let results = Foo.objectsWhere("people.@count = %d", 2)

// 'Invalid column name', reason: 'Column name @count not found in table'
let results = Foo.objectsWhere("ANY people.@count = %d", 2)
```

We've looked through multiple examples, Apple's docs on NSPredicate & other SO answers, and we can't seem to find an answer. How do we query for all objects based on the size of a RLMArray property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a  [limitation](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1490) of Realm until the release of version 0.96. Since then [Keypath Collection Queries](http://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/#keypath-collection-queries) are supported.

Comment: Bummer...thanks...hadn't seen that post--just came out a few days ago

Comment: Any plans for supporting this in a new version?

Comment: [Version 0.96](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0960-beta-release-notes-2015-10-07) brought support for this.

Comment: I have 0.97 v. And it still does not seem to work. NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(searchQueries, $query, $query.location == %@).@count > 0", argumentArray: ["London"]). This rises the 'Predicate expressions must compare a keypath and another keypath or a constant value'. And I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Subqueries are not fully supported yet. There is a [PR](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/2998) though, which will bring support for that once that's merged and released.

Comment: @Fawkes, subqueries are supported as of [Realm Objective-C and Swift 0.98.0](https://realm.io/news/realm-objc-swift-0.98.0/).

Comment: @bdash TNX! I'll try it out